# HTML Agility Pack 2

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am tring to scrap [This Website](http://www.edb.gov.hk/templates/sch_list_print.asp?district=cw) . 
The below Xpath expression working fine with FirePath firebug extension

```
html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td
```

But using same xpath expression the below code gives me null :

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

 doc = web.Load("http://www.edb.gov.hk/templates/sch_list_print.asp?district=cw");
 var collection= doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td");
```

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works, looking at the source of the page you are trying to scrape there is no tbody inside of table.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

doc = web.Load("http://www.edb.gov.hk/templates/sch_list_print.asp?district=cw");
var collection= doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("html/body/table/tr[3]/td");
```

change your xpath to

```
html/body/table/tr[3]/td
```

Comment: Oh great , the xpath I was using was generated by firepath , indeed there is no tbody in the html , any idea ??

Comment: it is automaticly "fixed" when the DOM is loaded and there are tables missing tbody. lots of stuff can happen to the DOM after and when a page is loaded, you always need to view the raw source to see what is actually there.

remember to mark the answer as the correct answer if it fixed your problem :)

Comment: Any other useful pointer for scrapping job with agility pack ?